# Is it possible to unzip a file in 7zip file format using Google Apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, unzip, 7zip

I've been able to successfully unzip a regular zip file easily using Google Apps Script.  However, a program I use outputs certain files zipped using 7zip.  Is there a way to unzip a 7zip file in Google Apps script?

Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using Google App Script Unzip a file from Google Drive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45284798/using-google-app-script-unzip-a-file-from-google-drive)

Comment: Maybe setting the file type as a zip file will work if I do that first.  I'll try it and report back.  Thank you.

Comment: This did not appear to work.  I believe that 7zip is completely different from the standard zip format that GAS is used to working with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google Apps Script does not support 7 zip out of the box. It only supports [Gzip](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#gzipblob) and [Zip](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#zipblobs).

However with the time and knowledge necessary, you can get an open source extension written in javascript and re-write it to Apps Script, just be aware that if the extension has dependencies you will have to re-write the dependencies as well.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try converting to zip file with cloudconvert api first (free for up to 25 conversions per day)
https://cloudconvert.com/api/v2/jobs/builder

**ENDPOINT**

POST https://api.cloudconvert.com/v2/jobs

**REQUEST BODY**

```
{
    "tasks": {
        "import-1": {
            "operation": "import/url",
            "url": "https://notepad-plus-plus.org/repository/7.x/7.0/npp.7.bin.minimalist.x64.7z"
        },
        "task-1": {
            "operation": "convert",
            "input_format": "7z",
            "output_format": "zip",
            "engine": "archivetool",
            "input": [
                "import-1"
            ]
        },
        "export-1": {
            "operation": "export/url",
            "input": [
                "task-1"
            ],
            "inline": false,
            "archive_multiple_files": false
        }
    }
}
```

**Create new API key:** https://cloudconvert.com/dashboard/api/v2/keys

**Google AppScript:**

```
function cloudConvert7ztoZip() {
// Make a POST request with a JSON payload.
var data = {
    "tasks": {
        "import-1": {
            "operation": "import/url",
            "url": "https://notepad-plus-plus.org/repository/7.x/7.0/npp.7.bin.minimalist.x64.7z"
        },
        "task-1": {
            "operation": "convert",
            "input_format": "7z",
            "output_format": "zip",
            "engine": "archivetool",
            "input": [
                "import-1"
            ]
        },
        "export-1": {
            "operation": "export/url",
            "input": [
                "task-1"
            ],
            "inline": true,
            "archive_multiple_files": true
        }
    }
}
var headers = {
        'Authorization': 'Bearer CLOUDCONVERT API KEY'
    };

var options = {
  'method' : 'post',
  'contentType': 'application/json',
  'headers': headers,
  // Convert the JavaScript object to a JSON string.
  'payload' : JSON.stringify(data)
  };

 var response = JSON.parse(UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://api.cloudconvert.com/v2/jobs', options));

 var dataID = response.data.id;

  var options2= = {
  'method' : 'get',
  'contentType': 'application/json',
  'headers': headers,
  };
  
  // if the file is too big wait a few seconds
  // Utilities.sleep(3000);

  var urlStatus = 'https://api.cloudconvert.com/v2/jobs/'+dataID+'/wait'
  var conversionStatus = JSON.parse(UrlFetchApp.fetch(urlStatus, options2));
  Logger.log(conversionStatus.data.tasks[0].result.files);
 
}
```

Reference:

https://cloudconvert.com/api/v2

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#fetch(String,Object)

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities?hl=en#sleep(Integer)