# javascript - unzip tar.gz archive in google script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I am trying to unzip the file: [https://wwwinfo.mfcr.cz/ares/ares_vreo_all.tar.gz][1] into google drive folder.

So, I have downloaded the file using google script, but can not properly unzip it. Could you, please, help me with it?

Thank you in advance!

Update:
Here is my code

```
function updateDB() {
  var url = 'https://wwwinfo.mfcr.cz/ares/ares_vreo_all.tar.gz';
  var blob = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getBlob();
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById('fileid');
  var archive = folder.createFile(blob);
  unzip(archive);
}

function unzip(archive){
  var zipblob = archive.getBlob();
  var uncompressed1 = Utilities.ungzip(zipblob);
}
```

So I receive the following error:

```
Exception: Could not decompress gzip.
```

I guess it does not decompress normally, that is why I am asking if you would know different way
[1]: https://wwwinfo.mfcr.cz/ares/ares_vreo_all.tar.gz

Comment: Skip the drive. Try ungzip directly

Comment: Tried, same exception :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `Utilities` Class to unzip your File.

To unzip the gzip you have to call the `ungzip()` method:

```
var textBlob = Utilities.newBlob("Some text to compress using gzip compression");

// Create the compressed blob.
var gzipBlob = Utilities.gzip(textBlob, "text.gz");

// Uncompress the data.
var uncompressedBlob = Utilities.ungzip(gzipBlob);
```

That's the example provided in the official [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#ungzip(BlobSource)).

You can also take a look at the answer given [to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45284798/using-google-app-script-unzip-a-file-from-google-drive) that also explains how to use the `Utilities` Class in combination with Google Drive.

Comment: Hello Diazed, thank you for your response! I have updated the question with my code and exception that I am getting. I already looked at the documentation, but don't know why it is not working :(

Comment: Hello, i tried running your code with a different gzip to unzip. 
It worked as expected and did not throw any Exception.
I used `https://dlcdn.apache.org/tomcat/tomcat-9/v9.0.62/bin/apache-tomcat-9.0.62.tar.gz` for my test. 
Seems like there's something off with the gzip you're downloading.

Comment: I also think there is something wrong with the file, mb because it is very large. Anyway, thank you for help and good luck :)

Comment: @nikita1221 Your intuition is correct. `UrlfetchApp.fetch()` limits responses to no more than 50MB (see [quotas](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas)). Your file is 588MB. You might be able to download the file in chunks and stitch it back together but you'll probably run into timeout errors (6-minute limit on script runtime).